# Clear cells across two or more sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, cell

I have the following simple script which deletes a range of cells from one sheet. How can I amend this so that I can specify cells across more than one sheet? I assume it's something to do with changing getSheetByName? Many thanks.

```
function clearandover() {
  //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Andover');
  sheet.getRange('B8:G').clearContent();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just going to do one command on each sheet, it doesn't help you to define the sheet in a separate value. You can just do it like this:

```
function clearandover() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Andover').getRange('B8:G').clearContent();
  spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Second sheet name').getRange('B8:G').clearContent();
  spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Third sheet name').getRange('B8:G').clearContent();
}
```

Of course you can change the range per sheet that needs to be cleared.